# Background image responding to height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want my jumbotron background to automatically adjust its height to the screen resolution. At the same time, the width of the image would change only with the same ratio as height, and the rest of width would be hidden.

For example I have this image:
[image: example]

And it shows only part of its height and width.

[image: example]

```
<div id="j-ricardo" class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>David Ricardo</h1>
        <p>Najbogatszy ekonomista w historii</p>
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    #j-ricardo {
        background-image: url("obrazki/ricardo.jpg");
        background-size: 100% auto;
        height: 15%;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Background-size: contain; doesn't work like this (the image repeats itself). I want to use HTML and CSS only, no jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use contain with `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: But "contain" makes both height and width try to fit. I want only height to. The width should change only when height changes, and now they both are fitting.

Comment: try background-size: auto 100%;